# how to make a new eclipse project (as a plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there, somewhere a tutorial on how to make an eclipse plugin.
need it to integrate as a NEW PROJECT into eclipse.

I've seen others, but not for making a NEW PROJECT plugin.

or is there an existing open source plugin i could check for tips and tricks... could not find it, eclipse list of plugins is crazy to search through.

Comment: Try this: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/) as well as [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) tutorial look rather promising for beginning plugin development. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592391/eclipse-plugin-development-resources. For wizards, check [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-custwiz/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=GR&ca=dgr-eclipse-1).

Comment: Speed development with Eclipse wizards (last link) really helped

Comment: The "this tutorial" link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse.org officially suggests [**THIS BLOG**](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) to start developing the eclipse plugins.

This will give you an understanding on where to start, how to write and how to generate it as a plugin and deploy it.

Posts given by @Dirk also will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials on Eclipse RCP on the Internet, on the following link from the chapter Tutorials *Writing an Eclipse Plug-in (Part 1)* to *Writing an Eclipse Plug-in (Part 6)* will be helpful:

http://lubospeclipse.wordpress.com/eclipse-plugin-and-rcp-development-notes-2-2/

Also, if you want to check an existing Open Source Eclipse plugin which does the same thing, the best way do is to find plugins made for new languages of technologies. Basically, every new language or technology first implements plugins for new project and for custom file type.